# Can i send the iOS simulator file?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way to send the iOS simulator file only and no source code, i just want my app to be tested

Comment: Even if it is possible to do this, you should not rely on the simulator for testing purposes. With that said, I would start by copying the application from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{VERSION}/Applications/` I have a good feeling it's not going to work out though.

Comment: oh ok, can i use it on my phone without putting it on the app store? sorry i'm just new at this

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano, You need a developer profile or distribution profile for that. You cant do it without that.

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano, So were you planning to put it in an iPhone or simulator? If it is for simulator, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, even if you did send the simulator binary it wouldn't deploy on the other devices (certificates, and code signing). Proper protocol would be to add the other devices to your portal, and if they don't have them already, send them the necessary certificates, private keys, etc. Along with that data you can attach a binary used for testing. If you have any more questions or need clarification just let me know!

Comment: Simulator binaries wouldn't work on devices in any case being that they are compiled down to i386 instruction sets. Device binaries are compiled down to ARM instruction sets. A moot point for this discussion, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an AdHoc distribution.

There are also a lot of automation tools for that out there, one of the most popular and my choice, being TestflightApp.

They also have a very good documentation to get you started!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the simulator build to someone else and ask them to put it in their simulator build location. They will be able to run the application in simulator without the source code then.

In order to do this go to,

```
Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0
```

and copy the folder which looks like `0BE5DCF2-7F78-4D3G-BE5E-41268C635784`(Make sure your app file is present in that folder as `yourproject.app` file) and send that folder to the other person. Ask them to put in the same location. Make sure that the simulator is closed before doing this on the other computer.

Note that the above solution works only for the simulator and not for iPhone device. You cannot put this in an iPhone. If you want to put the build to an iPhone, you might have to get a distribution profile and add the other device in that and then send the ipa file so that the tester can put it their device.

Please note that for testing, it is better to not to depend on the simulator. It is always better to test in an actual iPhone device.

Comment: Have you tried this before?

Comment: @Lefteris, Yes, sending simulator build is possible. I have done it in the past. You can try it out yourself, if you wish.

Comment: Fun fact! I thought copying it may work but had a suspicion it may not. Thanks for sharing.